# How to define Alarm Events in FIWARE entities (NGSI)

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

Is there any common practise to define alarm events in FIWARE data model entities? I mean if we have devices sending alarm events like for example if we currentTooHigh. Something like this:

```
"currentTooHigh": {
            "type": "Text",
            "value": "off",
            "metadata": {
                "dateStarted": {
                    "type": "DateTime",
                    "value": "2021-09-18T12:02:49.000Z"
                }
                "dateUpdated": {
                    "type": "DateTime",
                    "value": "2021-09-18T16:02:49.000Z"
                }
            }
```

perhaps also add a some severity attribute as metadata , like info, warning, error and failure. etc.. or something

I am asking how it is already being done so I do not have to make something up new.

I received clarification about how to handle these alarm events. Thanks!  next question, when the value is returning to a normal value and thus threshold is not breached anymore, then the alarm state is OK. What happens then?  I may have a service/app accessing/subscribing to some entity/attrbute in the context broker via NGSI API in order to keep a log of the mentioned alarm events and then provide some alarm log similar to the attached picture.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since I noticed you are using NGSIv2 (you are talking about metadata), I leave here  NGSIv2 examples of data models mentioned in another comment:

**[Alerts](https://smart-data-models.github.io/dataModel.Alert/Alert/examples/example-normalized.json)**

```json
{
  "id": "Alert:1",
  "type": "Alert",
  "dateCreated": {
    "type": "DateTime",
    "value": "2019-06-06T12:06:06"
  },
  "dateModified": {
    "type": "DateTime",
    "value": "2019-06-07T12:07:06"
  },
  "category": {
    "value": "traffic"
  },
  "subCategory": {
    "value": "trafficJam"
  },
  "validTo": {
    "type": "DateTime",
    "value": "2017-01-02T10:25:55.00Z"
  },
  "description": {
    "value": "The road is completely blocked for 3kms"
  },
  "location": {
    "type": "geo:json",
    "value": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [-3.712247222222222, 40.423852777777775]
    }
  },
  "dateIssued": {
    "type": "DateTime",
    "value": "2017-01-02T09:25:55.00Z"
  },
  "alertSource": {
    "value": "https://account.lab.fiware.org/users/8"
  },
  "validFrom": {
    "type": "DateTime",
    "value": "2017-01-02T09:25:55.00Z"
  },
  "severity": {
    "value": "high"
  }
}
```

**[Anomaly](https://smart-data-models.github.io/dataModel.Alert/Anomaly/examples/example-normalized.json)**

```json
{
  "id": "1863179e-3768-4480-9167-ff21f870dd19",
  "type": "Anomaly",
  "detectedBy": {
    "type": "Relationship",
    "object": "urn:ngsi-ld:Device:1863179e-3868-4480-3496-jf21f090dd20"
  },
  "anomalousProperty": {
    "type": "Text",
    "value": "Pressure"
  },
  "dateDetected": {
    "type": "DateTime",
    "value": "2021-01-14T15:45:00Z"
  },
  "thresholdBreach": [
    {
      "type": "StructuredValue",
      "value": {
        "dateObserved": {
          "type": "DateTime",
          "value": "2021-01-14T15:30:00Z"
        },
        "measuredValue": {
          "type": "Number",
          "value": 18.91
        },
        "thresholdType": {
          "type": "Text",
          "value": "LOWER"
        },
        "thresholdValue": {
          "type": "Number",
          "value": 20
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "StructuredValue",
      "value": {
        "dateObserved": {
          "type": "DateTime",
          "value": "2021-01-14T15:45:00Z"
        },
        "measuredValue": {
          "type": "Number",
          "value": 18.91
        },
        "thresholdType": {
          "type": "Text",
          "value": "LOWER"
        },
        "thresholdValue": {
          "type": "Number",
          "value": 20
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: The original [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69446701/1179828) was just key-values, if you return normalized NGSI-v2 you'll get the format shown [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69451707/1179828). There are also other formats e.g. CSV, NGSI-LD etc. available within the [dataModel.Alert](https://smart-data-models.github.io/dataModel.Alert/) SmartDataModels webpages

Comment: Thanks. What happens when value resume to a non alarm state (below the threshold  value)?

Comment: @Green1234 there are several options, depending on how the entity is processed. The one described in the data model (Anomaly) is intended to be created each time the threshold is breached. This means each time there is an anomaly, an entity is created. With the last value of the attribute thresholdBreach you can model when the anormaly condition stops.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to align your data entities to common data models, you should check out the [Smart Data Models](https://smartdatamodels.org/) Initiative, this holds a series of practical FIWARE data models which are already in use. Either of the following may reasonably form the basis of your alarm event:

- [Alert](https://swagger.lab.fiware.org/?url=https://smart-data-models.github.io/dataModel.Alert/Alert/swagger.yaml)
- [Anomaly](https://swagger.lab.fiware.org/?url=https://smart-data-models.github.io/dataModel.Alert/Anomaly/swagger.yaml)

```json
{
  "id": "1863179e-3768-4480-9167-ff21f870dd19",
  "type": "Anomaly",
  "detectedBy": "urn:ngsi-ld:Device:1863179e-3868-4480-3496-jf21f090dd20",
  "anomalousProperty": "Pressure",
  "dateDetected": "2021-01-14T15:45:00Z",
  "thresholdBreach": [
    {
      "dateObserved": "2021-01-14T15:30:00Z",
      "measuredValue": 18.91,
      "thresholdType": "LOWER",
      "thresholdValue": 20
    },
    {
      "value": "2021-01-14T15:45:00Z",
      "measuredValue": 18.91,
      "thresholdType": "LOWER",
      "thresholdValue": 20
    }
  ]
}
```